# Enterprise Library 5.0 w/ WPF. The first element is not validated at load in a collection with DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, validation, enterprise-library

I use this forum for quite some time and finally found an issue that wasn't answered before so this is my first topic here.

Anyway, I've made a small program to check the validation manager in the Enterprise Library 5.0 and found a bug (?) in it while using it in Collections with DataTemplate in order to see the type specified.

The problem is that the first object is loaded up without the red square (meaning it's valid) when in fact it is not. only after changing it a bit it is getting the red square (meaning after adding a letter or removing one).
All other objects in the collection works great at load time, only the first one is acting different.

Any clue?

---

### **Window.xaml.cs:**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Collection = new ObservableCollection<NewClass>();

            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                Collection.Add(new NewClass()
                {
                    ID = i,
                    Name = "Example" + i
                });

            }

            this.stackPanel.DataContext = this;
            this.listBox.ItemsSource = Collection;

        }

        public ObservableCollection<NewClass> Collection;
```

---

### **NewClass**

```
 public class NewClass
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

---

### **Window.xaml**

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NewClass}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBox Margin="10,10,10,10" vab:Validate.BindingForProperty="Text" vab:Validate.ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" 
                Text="{Binding Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>


<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="stackPanel">
    <ListBox Margin="10,0,0,0" x:Name="listBox"  />
</StackPanel>
```

---

### **App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="validation" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Configuration.ValidationSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />
  </configSections>

  <validation>
    <type name="EntLibTest.NewClass" defaultRuleset="ValidationRuleset"
  assemblyName="EntLibTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null">
      <ruleset name="ValidationRuleset">
        <properties>
          <property name="Name">
            <validator type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Validators.StringLengthValidator, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
          upperBound="3" lowerBoundType="Inclusive" negated="false" name="String Length Validator" />
          </property>
        </properties>
      </ruleset>
    </type>
  </validation>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because you're validating when the target gets updated, not when its first loaded

A better way of doing validation in WPF is to have your class implement `IDataErrorInfo`, and put your validation logic in there.

Comment: That is indeed when I'm validating - when the target get's updated.

For simple validation rules, I would like to use an external configuration file without any code involvement.
For complex validation rules, I will have to use the IDataErrorInfo interface and structure.

Is there any way to get the target validated on load or refreshed in some sort to fix this issue?
I've tried RefreshBinding and it didn't work.